# Unable to make producer for kinesis video stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to implement producer as mentioned here(https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/demo/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/demoapp/PutMediaDemo.java).

I have a mkv file which i want to upload in loop to act as producer in Kinesis video stream. But program hangs on line 122 (latch.await()). Program stuck at this line without giving any error and i am not able to see any thing on amazon video preview tab.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The line 122 (latch.await()) is waiting for acknowledge or connection close event. It could be firewall or network condition causing this to wait for ever…. Before you try your own mkv file, were you able to get the demo running with the sample mkv files and see playback in the console?  Let us know if that succeeds in your environment.